# How can I automatically save a list of open files in Geany, with cron or otherwise?

Tags: linux, sudo, cron, geany

I use the Geany IDE for programming, and it does not reliably reload my previously open files, for example after a power outage. I found that Geany has a command line feature which returns a list of all open files in the editor, so I hoped that I could quickly write a cron command that would automatically save that list every hour or so.

I currently have this line in my crontab:

```
0 * * * * ~/bin/save_geany_files
```

and the script contains just one line:

```
geany --list-documents > ~/geany_files.txt
```

This does not work. I noticed that Geany's --list-documents feature must be called by the same user (I think), so I tried adding "su - [myusername]" to the script, but apparently su cannot be used from within a cron job? So, I am at a loss for how to automate this. I am open to any other solutions to my problem, although Geany options/plugins seem to be unreliable (which is why I tried this in the first place)

Comment: Have you made `~/bin/save_geany_files` executable? It should work without the `su` (cron jobs are run by the user whose crontab it is) as long as the "script" (not really a script) is executable.

Comment: Commands in your crontab (i.e. added via `crontab` without a `-u` argument) run under your account by default. Unless you're running `geany` as a user other than yourself, which seems mildly unlikely, the problem has to be somewhere else, e.g., with @terdon's suggestion that maybe the shell script isn't executable.

Comment: And, as a more general solution, you might consider using a more reliable editor; I've found Emacs (which has long-standing and well-tested session save and restore facilities) quite suitable. (I know -- "Emacs? Augh!" -- but don't believe the hype! Emacs is extremely intuitive, once you've spent several years learning how it works. :)

Comment: @terdon: Yes, the file is executable. I thought cron jobs were run as the owner, but I put in a debugging line, `echo "user: $USER"`, and in the output it shows just `user: `, so I'm confused. I'm not running Geany as a different user.

Comment: I'm not opposed to learning emacs, but that's something I'd do on my own time, so it will have to wait for a while.

Answer (score 3):

By running the crontab like this:

```
0 * * * * ~/bin/save_geany_files 2> /tmp/geanyerror.log
```

I found this error message in /tmp/geanyerror.log:

```
Geany: cannot open display
```

I solved this by adding the following line to .bashrc:

```
xhost local:arune > /dev/null
```

(where arune is my username)
and changing my crontab to

```
0 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && ~/bin/save_geany_files 2> /tmp/geanyerror.log
```

My own save_geany_files-script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /home/arune/geany/savenew.txt /home/arune/geany/saveold.txt
/usr/bin/geany --list-documents > /home/arune/geany/savenew.txt
```

to store a "backup" for one hour extra.